# Why my cfloop stop after inserting first id?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, insert

I created cfloop that goes through query that I created above the loop. Inside of the loop I have another loop that defines values and then cfquery with insert statement. I tested my loops before I tried to insert my records in database and everything looked good. After I tried to apply that to insert my records my insert statement terminates after inserting first records from my . Here is example of my code:

```
<cfloop query="qryRecords">
    <cfloop condition="TimeStart LTE meetingLength">
        <cfset TimeEnd = dateAdd("n", arguments.meeting, TimeStart)>
        <cfquery name="addRecords" datasource="test">
            Insert Into(Date,Name,Location)
            Values(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#arguments.date#">,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" value="#Name#">,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#Location#">);
        </cfquery>
        <cfset TimeStart = dateAdd("n", arguments.meeting, TimeStart)>          
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

In my qryRecords I have 40+ records and I should insert multiple time records. My insert do that just for the first record and stop. Like I mentioned above I tried to output that on the screen with this code:

```
<cfloop query="qryRecords">
    <cfloop from="#test.Stime#" to="#test.Etime#" index="i" step="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,test.meetingLeng,0)#">
                <cfset TimeEnd = dateAdd("n", test.meetingLeng, i)>
                    <tr>
                        <td>(#ID#) #timeFormat(TimeStart, "hh:mm tt")# - #timeFormat(TimeEnd, "hh:mm tt")#</td>
                    </tr>
                <cfset TimeStart = dateAdd("n", test.meetingLeng, i)>           
            </cfloop>       
</cfloop>
```

My output after I tested this code looks like this:

```
    (3) 08:30 AM - 08:40 AM
    (3) 08:40 AM - 08:50 AM
    (3) 08:50 AM - 09:00 AM
    (3) 09:00 AM - 09:10 AM
    (3) 09:10 AM - 09:20 AM
    (3) 09:20 AM - 09:30 AM
    (3) 09:30 AM - 09:40 AM
   *(12) 09:40 AM - 08:40 AM
    (12) 08:40 AM - 08:50 AM
    (12) 08:50 AM - 09:00 AM
    (12) 09:00 AM - 09:10 AM
    (12) 09:10 AM - 09:20 AM
    (12) 09:20 AM - 09:30 AM
    (12) 09:30 AM - 09:40 AM
   *(23) 09:40 AM - 08:40 AM
    (23) 08:40 AM - 08:50 AM
    .......... so on.
```

I can't see anything wrong with my Insert query and why that stops after inserting just one sequence of records in db. If anyone can see where I'm making mistake in my code please let me know.

Comment: The code you posted attempts to insert the same values into your table each time through the loop.  Also, the code you use to output stuff has different logic than what is there to insert records.

Comment: Yes I want to insert same values multiple times for different ID. That logic still should do the same thing as one for the output code.

Comment: First of all, how are you getting above output using this : `(#Id#) - #timeFormat(i, "hh:mm tt")# - #timeFormat(i, "hh:mm tt")#` ??

Comment: My bad, this is how <td>(#Id#) - #timeFormat(TimeStart, "hh:mm tt")# - #timeFormat(TimeEnd, "hh:mm tt")#</td>

Comment: @user3023588 Ok, then update your question. You have two different conditions in both code. Verify this: `TimeStart LTE meetingLength`.

Comment: You have two different loop conditions. That is why you are seeing differences. You query insert loop is using `<cfloop condition="TimeStart LTE meetingLength">` but your output loop is using `<cfloop from="#test.Stime#" to="#test.Etime#" index="i" step="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,test.meetingLeng,0)#">`. And there is no way that output is from the code you posted. You are outputting the same time value for `i` each time using `<td>(#Id#) - #timeFormat(i, "hh:mm tt")# - #timeFormat(i, "hh:mm tt")#</td>` but your output shows different values. It's hard to help if we aren't seeing the actual code.

Comment: I updated my question. I used <cfloop from="" to="" index="" step=""> and that gave me all records inserted in data base but another problem show up, after inserting first Record, my second Record starts where my first record end. I want that to be the same start time as my first record has. Do you know what is wrong in my loop? Thank you

Comment: If qryRecords doesn't contain a TimeStart column, then TimeStart needs to be reset between the 2 opening cfloop tags (btwn <cfloop query="qryRecords"> and <cfloop condition="TimeStart LTE meetingLength">). Also, the cfloop condition should be comparing TimeStart w/ the last slot's start time (not the meetingLength minutes).

Comment: That solved my problem, reset both start time and last slot's start time in between two loop's. Thank you for update.

Comment: Awesome, yvw, glad to hear!

Comment: @user3023588 added my comment as an answer in case you'd like to use it to mark this question as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If qryRecords doesn't contain a TimeStart column, then TimeStart needs to be reset between the 2 opening cfloop tags (btwn `<cfloop query="qryRecords">` and `<cfloop condition="TimeStart LTE meetingLength">`). Also, the cfloop condition should be comparing TimeStart w/ the last slot's start time (not the meetingLength minutes).